Post method is returning "This page is not working". Why?
I setup a basic login system. The <form class="login" action="/auth/login.php" method="post"> method is not working when testing it with print_r($_POST);.
<div class="login-wrapper">
    <form class="login" action="/auth/login.php" method="post">
            <section class="title">
                <h3 class="welcome">Welcome to</h3>
                <div class="welcome-app-title">
                    Market
                </div>
                <h5 class="hint">Use your username and password to sign or register <a class="btn btn-sm btn-link btn-no-margin custom-link-action" href="/register.html">here</a></h5>
            </section>
            <div class="login-group">
                <div class="clr-form-control">
                    <div class="clr-control-container ">
                        <div class="clr-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="clr-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="" type="text" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <span class="clr-subtext"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clr-form-control">
                    <div class="clr-control-container ">
                        <div class="clr-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="clr-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password" />
                        </div>
                        <span class="clr-subtext"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>

Any solutions?

First, find out where the message "This page is not working" is coming from. What HTTP server are you using? Does it have any error logs?

In what particular way does it not work? Browser gets a server response that is not 200? You get a PHP error message? $_POST is empty? The computer catches fire?

Does it work with a GET method or when you call that page directly in your browser?

@droopsnoot its giving me a "HTTP ERROR 405" each time I submit the information in the form.

@ÁlvaroGonzález loool each time I submit text into the form, it sends me to the Google "This page isn’t working" page, with the error "HTTP ERROR 405". any ideas?

@brombeer even after trying a get method, its redirecting me to the same page with the error "HTTP ERROR 405"

That's 405 Method Not Allowed. You don't typically get that unless you have some complicated arrangements, such as a web application firewall or custom PHP code to reject requests depending on request method. On a side note, don't spam comments repeating the same information. Just edit the question and provide it there.

@ÁlvaroGonzález Still a bit confused because the only code I have is whats present, besides css...

This is an issue with your server, so if you want help with that you have to add more information about your setup/server/hosting to your question. We don't even know if you have PHP installed.

This often occurs on local setups when people try to use a basic webserver which doesn't actually support  PHP, or even POST requests. The simple test server included with Visual Studio Code is a good example of this. Instead use a proper webserver like Apache to handle your php scripts.  A tool like XAMPP can make the setup of that very easy. What are you currently using to serve this page?

@ADyson Sorry, should I not be coding in VSCode?? All tutorials I see simply connect to a server, open a text editor, begin coding and open your php file. Im still getting the same message after hours of troubleshooting.

You can certainly code in VS Code, there's nothing to stop you doing that - with the PHP add-in it's a good IDE. But unfortunately you can't use its built-in webserver for actually running the PHP code, or at least not out of the box.

@ADyson wow, okay thank you. And that would explain why my php simply wont execute and print? That was driving me INSANE, so thank you.

Absolutely that's why, yes

@ADyson lastly, do you know of any other ides so I can avoid this and run both the html and php code?? or how I can in VSCode?

I think you are still not understanding the different kind of tools. Visual Studio Code is a text editor, the program you use to type code into files. PHP doesn't care how the file got created. To actually run PHP code you need the PHP interpreter, which is a different download. Before spending hours writing a complex application, I suggest you verify you can run a simple program like <?php echo 'Hello, World!';.

I don't  personally use anything else but you can research info about other PHP IDEs and their capabilities here. You may also be able to use add-ons such as this to enhance VS Code to do what you want - but again I haven't used anything like that so I can't promise that it gives a good experience. I would, in general, be wary of such things because it means the runtime environment is quite different than it would be when you deploy your code to a live server.

And anyway it's not complicated to install Apache and PHP via XAMPP. Then you write your code in VS Code, save it, and then open your browser, go to http://localhost and test your PHP code there.
